# Typescript typecasting D3.js DefaultArcObject

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I'm currently using the type definitions loaded from this [**package**](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-shape/index.d.ts). 
My code is attempting to set the `d` svg attribute of a `path` element using the `arc` generated by D3.js.

My code looks like the following:

```
const pie = d3.pie<SomeDataInterface>()
        .value((d) => d.dataVal);

const arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(mockData));

const path = d3.arc();

arc.append("path")
        .attr("d", path); // >> Where compilation fails
```

However, I receive this compilation error:

```
TypeScript error: Argument of type 'Arc<any, DefaultArcObject>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGPathElement, PieArcDatum<ID3Data>, string | number | boolean | null>'.
  Types of parameters 'd' and 'datum' are incompatible.
```

Looking at the example [**here**](https://github.com/Arlorean/D3-TypeScript-Example/blob/master/app.ts), it seems I can just declare an `<any>` type on the `path` declaration. Similarly, I've also tried importing the type definition of `Arc` using `import { Arc } from "d3-shape";` of which contains the actual type definition and assigning that like so:

```
.attr("d", <Arc>path)
```

of which also receives compilation warnings. Any idea what typecast I might be missing, and where specifically?

---

#### Update

This piece of code is working off the example shown [**here**](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/a73f9af9ccd9ef901a0c33c624096049).

Comment: Not familiar with `d3.js`, but are you trying to append the previouisly created `Arc` as `Datum`? Shouldn't that second argument be something else?

Comment: @Cristy yeah that path needs to be passed into the `d` attr of the path, I've added an example to my question illustrating the the code sample I'm working off from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it has been three years since the question was asked, in order to help those who come later, I would like to share the solution here.

To solve this problem, we need to modify the generic parameter of `d3.arc`. Assuming that our data type is `SomeDataInterface`, the generic parameter should be written like this:

```
d3.arc<d3.PieArcDatum<SomeDataInterface>>()
```

The key is to use `d3.PieArcDatum<>` to wrap our data type.